# TAM integration with custome web site

Tags: java

I want to integrate TAM with my web site for security and privacy. How can i integrate it with my web site.
My site is in java(jsp).

i used below command

```
server task <server-name> create -t tcp -h localhost  -p 9085 -c all /CustomeWebSealJunc
```

but still unable to integrate with TAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server task <websealed-instance> create -t tcp -h localhost -p 9080 -c all /<junction_name>
```

U can also us JAVA API for TAM Integration but for this first of all you need to used below command

```
java com.tivoli.pd.jcfg.SvrSslCfg -action config -admin_id sec_master -admin_pwd <password> -appsvr_id mts_java1 -port <port_no> -mode remote -port <port> -policysvr <host>:<port>:1 -authzsvr <host>:<port>:2 -cfg_file /opt/tamfiles/tamapi.conf -key_file /opt/tamfiles/tamapi.ks
```

this will create trust relationship with Java and Authorized server.